# onMessage.addListener Not Firing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I can't get chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener to fire no matter what examples I copy/paste around the web, even when I break them down as simply as I can. Right now I am using:

**Background JS**

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    var context = "selection";
    var title = "TM";
    var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({
        "title": title,
        "contexts":[context],
        "id": "context" + context
    }); 
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(onClickHandler);

function onClickHandler(info, tab) {
    chrome.windows.create(
        {url : 'URL Here'},
        function(window) {
            chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"});
            });
        }
    );
};
```

**Content Script**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log('onMessage fired');
});
```

The listener in the content script will just not fire. If I try to read the response from the sendMessage method then I get 'undefined'. The content script is loading and functioning correctly apart from this. I have double checked I am sending to the correct tab ID from grabbing that from the window object as well.

All I need to do is send the selected text over to the content script. I am new to Chrome extensions so don't know if I am missing something really obvious here!

Comment: How do you know that the context script is loaded? It might not yet be loaded at `windows.create` callback!

Comment: I am assuming everything is loading ok because I did have some other code in there which was working exactly as expected. I removed all of that just to see if it was stopping the message listener working though.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe you have a race condition here: the `chrome.windows.create` callback returns as the page is still loading, and there is no listener active yet.

To work around it, you can reverse the direction of the connection: send a message from the page to the background instead. In the background, you can compare window id of the sender with the newly created window if you need to discern tabs.

Comment: This makes perfect sense but still no luck! Sending a message from content script to the background which is received and then using sendResponse to send the required information back to the content script but the original sendMessage function doesn't get called like it isn't receiving a response.

Comment: The response sent with `sendResponse` is passed to the `sendMessage` callback, not the `onMessage` listener.

Comment: Yep I was responding from onMessage back to sendMessage. I have no idea what the problem is but using a long-lived connection works perfectly. Thanks for your help.